# how to extract all permissions that a domain user have on the network via php LDAP

Tags: permissions, active-directory, ldap

I would like to know all the permissions a domain user have in my network. Is there any php script,that can extract this kind of information by checking the server and computers in my network?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow; what have you already tried?

Comment: i have done authentication and get all users from Active directory via LDAP. Now i need to get user permissions?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no script to do this, and for good reason.

This is a big job that will likely never be 100%. There is no one place that all these permissions are stored, so you would have to decide what kind of permissions you are looking for and find those.

For example, a user could be:

- In permissions directly on AD objects (you would have to scan the permissions of every AD object in your domain)
- In permissions for files on servers (you would have to scan the entire file system of every server in your environment)
- In local groups on a computer, like Administrators (you would have to scan every local group on every computer in your domain, then scan the file system to see what permissions those groups have)

And when you do those scans, you have to look for any groups that the user is a member of too.

You have to decide how deep you want to go: a user could be given permissions on registry keys - do you want to find those too?

There also could be applications that could give permissions to AD groups or to users directly. The list goes on and on.